Why is this._super undefined the first time Odoo goes into an inherited JS function?
I'm using Odoo 16 and I'm inheriting from a JS function this way:
/** @odoo-module **/
import { StockBarcodeKanbanController } from '@stock_barcode/kanban/stock_barcode_kanban_controller';
import { patch } from 'web.utils';
import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks"; 

patch(StockBarcodeKanbanController.prototype, 'StockBarcodeKanbanControllerIchExt', { 
    setup() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.rpc = useService("rpc");
    },

    async openRecord(record) {
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
});

The openRecord function is called when I click on a kanban view card. It opens a special view of stock move lines, that is the original behaviour.
The problem is that the first time I click on the kanban card, a JS error is raised because this._super is undefined. However, if I skip the message and click again on the same kanban card, everything works OK because this._super has the expected value.
Why is this happening and what is the best way to solve it?
So far I did a monkey patch storing the original function in a variable and calling it instead of the super, but I would like to do it well.

There is an example in the official documentation which is also patching "setup". Did you try it that way?

It looks like my code, the difference is that I call this._super and in the example they call super. Do you mean that I should change that? In my setup function this._super worked.

I'm not a JS developer, so that's what i would try or die :D
